# Array.map is not rendering in Reat Native Function Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to render components with a loop. What I did was to use array.map inside a JSX return block of the function component. The component is to render each individual dates contained in the list called 'mountDates'. But it is not rendering the items. Here is my code:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {globalStyles} from '../../styles/global';
import AgendaItem from './agendaItem';

export default function Agenda({onDayChange, startDate, endDate}) {
  const mountDates = [];
  useEffect(() => {
    const getDates = (startDate, endDate) => {
      let currentDate = startDate;
      console.log(startDate, endDate);
      while (currentDate.getTime() <= endDate.getTime()) {
        mountDates.push(new Date(currentDate));
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
      }
    };
    getDates(startDate, endDate);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {mountDates.map((date, i) => {
        return <AgendaItem key={i.toString()} date={date} />;
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: To be honest I would use useCase in this situation for mountDates, I know since you are using useEffect it should be called once, but if this gets any bigger this will cause unexpected issues, In gerenal, things you show in the UI would be better of with useState, beside the fact that it would probaby solve your issue here, just console log mountDates before the return

Comment: You really should read React Docs, your code won't trigger render. Also your code makes more sense if you pass the `mountDates` as a prop.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use React.useState. which will trigger re-render when all data is set.

```
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {globalStyles} from '../../styles/global';
import AgendaItem from './agendaItem';

export default function Agenda({onDayChange, startDate, endDate}) {

  const [mountDates, setMountDates] = React.useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    const tempMountDates = [];
    const getDates = (startDate, endDate) => {
      let currentDate = startDate;
      console.log(startDate, endDate);
      while (currentDate.getTime() <= endDate.getTime()) {
        tempMountDates.push(new Date(currentDate));
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
      }
    };
    getDates(startDate, endDate);
    setMountDates();

  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {mountDates.map((date, i) => {
        return <AgendaItem key={i.toString()} date={date} />;
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are missing props at `dep` array, `[startDate, endDate]`, also you should set the state: `setMountDates(tempMountDates)`. Although the code will work it poorly designed, I think the `useEffect`'s logic should move to parent component or at least rewrite in immutable manner (not using `.push`)